# Choosing a Front End Framework for my ASP.NET CORE 2.0 social app

Tags: web-development, c#, angularjs, asp.net

I know this question is very broad, but I will try my best to explain properly needs of my app, so that you guys can suggest me simpler and proper way to proceed with the proper architecture of my app.

Everyone says I need to explain need of my app because these decisions depends on the app I am building so I will be explaining my app in this post.

**Application requirements :**

1. Social Network type app
2. Constant feed like twitter ( actually whole app will be almost like twitter, with some extra or changed features )
3. Geolocation sync between users.
4. Chatting option.

**Cloud :**

Any recommendation regarding cloud services must be in **Azure** because I have an azure subscription and want to use that.

**Platforms/Devices**

1. Web app ( **progressive web app**)
2. Xamarin Native ( Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.IOS and UWP )hence it will be mobile app as well

**Technologies preferred :**

3. ASP.NET CORE 2.0 ( because I have experience in C sharp ).
4. Visual Studio 2017 ( because of the great tooling )
5. Authentication with **Azure B2C**
6. Bootstrap and material design for UI.

**AIM :**

I want to share maximum code with **C-Sharp** so that I can write my buiseness logic only once and then use it accross my web app and also my mobile apps.

**Question :**

Which framework should I learn and use for this app? I know all frameworks can do this job but which one should be recommended for this particular scenario? so that it is **performant**, **easier to develop** and **easier to learn**.

> following are the frameworks I have been researching about and confused which one to choose.

1. Vue 2
2. Angular 4
3. React
4. Auriela
5. Polymer

Comment: I semi recently had the same question. I finally decided on using simple Javascript, Jquery and Mustache. I'm actually extremely happy with my decision.  No frameworks will be help/useful with an in depth knowledge of Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There won't really be a definite answer to this, but hey, this is a recommendations web site. Here's my recommendation:

Just pick one. You put Vue at the top of your list. You know it's good. Everybody out there knows it's good. It was the hot rising star of 2017. Pick it and don't look back. Work that Vue until you know it inside and out.

Is Vue really the best choice? It doesn't matter. It's completely capable and will live on for a while as an employable skill.

So that's really my recommendation. Just pick one and don't give up for at least 12 months.